# Find frequency of each similar word in a large text c#/sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, fulltext-index

I need to group words as similar and then find the frequence.

So text like `"moron and morons sat on moronic bench with mormons"` will yield result

```
Moron 3
Sat 1
Mormon 1
```

I need to be able to push a text or list of exact words in one query and receive generic words with frequency.

From C#, can use SQL Server.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID('database_name'),     OBJECT_ID('table_name') )`

Comment: Thanks I need some time to install sql to trst it. Put it as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-document-transact-sql):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID('db_name')‌​,OBJECT_ID('tab_name'))
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could add sql to build the full text index for it. For morons like me :) I need fts by words only no phrases or any fancy stuff.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C# version you can use `Regex` with Linq; like this:

```
var txt = "moron and morons sat on moronic bench with mormons";
var words = Regex.Matches(txt, @"\w+").OfType<Match>().Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
var result = words.Select(c => new {Word = c, Count = words.Count(w => w.Contains(c))})
                  .OrderByDescending(o=> o.Count).ToList();
```

### [`[ C# Fiddle Demo ]`](http://ideone.com/rTvk5o)

Comment: nope. it returns 9 items. its not question for regex anyway. thanks